# Use regular expression in for loop to copy files

Tags: bash, macos, for-loop, cp

I have a txt file with a list of partial file names. I would like to copy only those files in the txt file to another directory. However, I  need to use a regular expression to find the files. I can't seem to get it to work properly. Any suggestions?

```
$ cat file-names.txt

name1    ACTGC
name2    ACTGG
name3    AACTN

$ ls raw/

name1_R1.fastq.gz
name1_R2.txt
name2_R1.fastq.gz
name2_R2.txt
name3_R1.fastq.gz
name4_R2.txt
name5_R1.fastq.gz

$ for i in `cut -f1 file-names.txt` ; do cp raw/"$i"_*.gz ./ ; done
```

Unfortunately, this gives an error:

```
cp: raw/name1_*.gz: No such file or directory
cp: raw/name2_*.gz: No such file or directory
cp: raw/name3_*.gz: No such file or directory
```

How can I get `cp` or `rsync` to recognize the `*` wildcard instead of treating it as the literal filename?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are using globs here, not regular expressions.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Here's what I tried: `printf '%s\t%s\n' name1 ACTGC name2 ACTGG name3 AACTN > file-names.txt` to create the text file, `mkdir -p raw && touch raw/{name1_R1.fastq.gz,name1_R2.txt,name2_R1.fastq.gz,name2_R2.txt,name3_R1.fastq.gz,name4_R2.txt,name5_R1.fastq.gz}` to create the various files, then ``for i in `cut -f1 file-names.txt` ; do cp raw/"$i"_*.gz ./ ; done`` like you did. It worked as expected. Can you please try again in a new directory without reusing any of your existing files and see if the problem still persists?

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$ ls -1 name{1..5}*
name1_R1.fastq.gz
name1_R2.txt
name2_R1.fastq.gz
name2_R2.txt
name3_R1.fastq.gz
name4_R2.txt
name5_R1.fastq.gz
```

You can do this:

```
while read -r fn _; do    # no need for cut - shell can split
    ls -1 "${fn}_"*".gz"  # concatenate and expand this way
                          # "$fn"_*.gz works too
    # change to your cp as desired...
done <file-names.txt      # while loop best to loop over file in shell
```

Lists:

```
name1_R1.fastq.gz
name2_R1.fastq.gz
name3_R1.fastq.gz
```

---

BTW:

```
for i in `cut -f1 file-names.txt` ; do ls "$i"_*.gz ; done
```

Works on my computer. Not sure why it does not on your computer?

Comment: What was wrong with OP's attempt?

Comment: I deleted the comment since I tested. (You *do* need eval if the `*` is in a variable or quoted string...) His code actually works on my computer so I cannot say why it does not work for him.

Comment: there may be a `set -o noglob` in his script?